Unity app crushes when trying to launch it from another app (Oculus Quest 2)
I have a build of my VR Unity app for Oculus Quest 2 and it starts and works just fine. In addition for this app I have a launcher - an android 2D app that was written using .NET MAUI framework. This launcher allows to start Unity app by clicking "Launch" button. Here is button handler code:
static partial void PLaunch()
{
    PackageManager packageManager = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager;
    Intent intent = packageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(MainPage.appPackageName);
    MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
}

With VR headsets from another vendors this handler works as expected. It launches my Unity app as if it was launched directly. But in case of Oculus Quest 2 it tries to launch my Unity app inside of launcher window as 2D app and then it crushes. I want to figure out how to fix it.
Here is device logs for two scenarios:
direct_app_launch.txt - Unity app launches directly (works ok):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kIGc_p14XDXfwghB8ernp3QY7szBWg6L/view?usp=drive_link
launcher_app_launch.txt - Unity app launches using launcher (crash happening):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b3EaeV5-rWFZLmOotM36YpGacG4EEmtT/view?usp=drive_link
Package names
Unity app: com.stemgames.vics.studio
launcher: com.stemgames.vics_science_studio_launcher
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any clues. I will appreceate any help with this issue.
